# Java get a specific data in jsonarray

Tags: java, arrays

```
{"a":"AAA","b":32.4,"c":34.65},
{"a":"AAM","b":10.8,"c":11.55}
```

I use JSONArray to get jsonarray above. I want to use this code get data `b:10.8` if `a:AAM`.

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{ 
  String get = sql.getQuote();
  JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(get);
  for (int i = 0; i<jsonarray.length();i++){
    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String symbol = obj.getString("a");
    if (symbol.equals("AAM")){
      double price = obj.getDouble("b");
      System.out.println(price);
    } else { 
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me to fix it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what wrong with your code? It doesn't work or throw exception or you can't compile it. Describe your problem.

Comment: Your code checks the first element, then if it's not something starting with `"a"` it exits the loop.

Comment: the code above cannot get data of 10.8 . But there is an answer below. Thanks for your review.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `else` statement in `for-loop`.

Remove `else` block i.e.

```
 else { 
         break;
      }
```

In your code, `else` block stops the `for-loop` on very first iteration. Because here `"a":"AAA"`. Since the condition `if (symbol.equals("AAM"))` is `false` so `else` block is executing which further breaks the loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the break in the else, just take it out.
If anywhere, it would be most appropriate in the if part:

```
if (symbol.equals("AAM")) {
    System.out.println(obj.getDouble("b"));
    break; // or leave it out if there might be a second AAM entry
}
```